# InsertHelper clarification needed

Tags: android, sqlite

From the doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html

What does this line means?

> but compile the SQL insert statement only once,

Please explain, i am not able to understand this.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getDatabaseFromSomewhere();

db.insert("tableName", null, contentValues1);
db.insert("tableName", null, contentValues2);
db.insert("tableName", null, contentValues3);
```

each time you call `insert` Android will create a new SQLiteStatement. If you do the same with an InsertHelper it creates only 1 statement and reuses that which may be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The InsertHelper class takes x-amount of INSERT statements (say 5) and executes them in one statement, which is faster since 1 < 5;